# Bash errors if I have more than one else statement

Tags: bash, bluetooth, beacon

So I have been teaching myself bash script for this project at work. I am using RadBeacon Bluetooth beacons and a raspberry pi to automate bus audio when buses drive past a certain location. Here is my current code:

```
    while :
do
    sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh
    sleep 1
done
```

This sets the scan parameters and runs the second piece which reads the scans and executes what I need.

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA5 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/01intro.mp3 else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/02togravesite.mp3 else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA7 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/03gravesite.mp3 else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA8 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/04visitorcenter.mp3 else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA9 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/05conclusion.mp3   
    else
    sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh
fi
done
```

If I just do one if then statement the code runs without issue however when I go to multiple it tells me there is an unexpected token near "done." I have been researching this and trying different fomratting to no avail. Does anyone know the issue I am having?

Thanks a ton for your help in advance!

Comment: Try shellcheck.net

Comment: Thanks! using it now and its showing a few things

Answer (score 1):

Use the `elif` keyword:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA5 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/01intro.mp3
    elif [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/02togravesite.mp3
    elif [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA7 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/03gravesite.mp3
    elif [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA8 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/04visitorcenter.mp3
    elif [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA9 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/05conclusion.mp3   
    else
     sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh
    fi
done
```

Or better yet, use a `case` statement:

```
while read line
do
    case $line of
    "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA5 0 1"*) f=01intro.mp3 ;;
    "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 0 1"*) f=02togravesite.mp3 ;;
    "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA7 0 1"*) f=03gravesite.mp3 ;;
    "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA8 0 1"*) f=04visitorcenter.mp3 ;;
    "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA9 0 1"*) f=05conclusion.mp3 ;;
    esac

    if [[ $f ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/"$f"
    else
      sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh ;;
    fi
done
```

Otherwise, you have a large number of separate `if` statements, one per `else`, that each need to be terminated by a `fi`. Also, each `else` needs to be preceded by a `;` if it isn't on the next line.

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA5 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/01intro.mp3; else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/02togravesite.mp3; else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA7 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/03gravesite.mp3; else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA8 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/04visitorcenter.mp3; else
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA9 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/05conclusion.mp3   
    else
      sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh
    fi; fi; fi; fi; fi
done
```

(The same with different indentation to emphasize the separate `if`s:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA5 0 1"* ]]; then
      mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/01intro.mp3
    else
      if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 0 1"* ]]; then
        mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/02togravesite.mp3
      else
        if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA7 0 1"* ]]; then
          mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/03gravesite.mp3
        else
          if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA8 0 1"* ]]; then
            mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/04visitorcenter.mp3
          else
            if [[ $line = "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA9 0 1"* ]]; then
              mplayer /home/pi/Desktop/05conclusion.mp3   
            else
              sudo beacon scan -A -b -d 4| /home/pi/Desktop/test3.sh
            fi
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didnt know that there needed to be multiple fi but looking at it no that makes much more sense! elif seems like a more elegant solution I will try to implement that instead. Again thanks a ton

Comment: I deleted my answer. Yours is the real deal.